# Как правильно указать минимальную ширину для элемента CSS grid, если мы не знаем заранее, сколько места оставит родительский контейнер?

Tags: css, css-grid

Задавая `grid-template-columns` значение например, `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));` мы предполагаем, что родительский контейнер будет всегда оставлять нам не менее `280px` (а иначе произойдёт переполнение контейнера). В реальности, разрабатывая компонент, мы не можем знать, какую ширину оставит нам родительский контейнер.

В этом примере, верхний макет с красноватым фоном демонстрирует обычный грид, которой нормально отображается на относительно широких экранах. Нижний макет с желтоватым фоном имитирует узкие экраны, при этот содержит в себе тот же самый грид. Как видно, элементы грида вылезают за пределы компоновки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Практический пример: grid со свойством `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr))` перестал влезать в экран, когда паддинги (обозначены зелёным цветом) сделали побольше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Честно говоря, тут я даже не знаю, как концептуально решить проблему, если нам нужно, чтобы элементы растягивались и сжимались по мере изменения ширины экрана... Какие-нибудь существуют походы для решения этой проблемы?

```css
.layout1 {
  background: #FAE5D3;
}

.layout2 {
  width: 230px;
  background: #FCF3CF;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 12px
}

.grid-item {
  background: #73C6B6;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout1">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="layout2">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если это построение небольших карточек как в Google keep то они это сделали через js иной способ я пока еще не видел. Видел только как делают уже с имеющимися данными

Comment: Или же можешь почитать тут: https://css-live.ru/articles/kak-rabotaet-funkciya-minmax.html Думаю больше всего подходит auto

Comment: Напишите короткий сниппет для демонстрации вашей проблеммы, пожалуйста

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущий комент. Пишите сниппет. С ваших слов ничего не понятно. Помимо функции `minmax()` есть еще функции `min()` и `max()`, которые пока еще работают и их можно комбинировать. Что-то вроде `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(280px, .8vw), 1fr));`. Мне даже очень сложно предположить, где бы пригодилась подобная конструкция. Остальные проблемы с различными экранами можно решить медиа-запросами.

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, добавил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите, чтобы при изменении размеров окна браузера элементы страницы переформатировались автоматически без наползания друг на друга.

Можно использовать 4 подхода.

0. Лобовой. Задать родителю атрибут [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width), чтобы он не сжимался больше допустимого.
1. Программистский. Использовать Javascript. Обработчик [`onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) вычисляет размер видимой области и из каких-то соображений форматирует содержимое страницы. Метод работает гарантированно, но бывает очень трудоёмко.
2. Избыточный. Использовать несколько заранее разработанных форматов элементов для страниц разной ширины и переключать их видимость в зависимости от ширины экрана. В вашем случае я бы сделал несколько вариантов вёрстки. Для узких экранов - в одну колонку. Для экранов пошире - в две. Для совсем широких - четыре. Условия для [`@media min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) считал бы из тех соображений, чтобы сами карточки выглядели красиво, и их дизайн был бы одинаковым для всех типов экранов.

Это несколько оверкилл в плане трафика, зато легко сделать. Оно как бы нехорошо, что вы отдаёте клиенту три копии одной и той же информации. Но с другой стороны, каналы связи сейчас безразмерные, десяток килобайт туда-сюда не играют роли.

```
  <style>
  .cell { display: inline; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .mobile-layout { display: block; }
    .tablet-layout { display: none; }
    .desktop-layout { display: none; }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .mobile-layout { display: none; }
    .tablet-layout { display: block; }
    .desktop-layout { display: none; }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .mobile-layout { display: none; }
    .tablet-layout { display: none; }
    .desktop-layout { display: block; }
  }
  </style>
<div class="mobile-layout">
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="tablet-layout">
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="desktop-layout">
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

3. Мейнстреймовый. Использовать [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/). Он за счёт игры с fluid атрибутами может делать так, что на широких экранах ячейки таблиц будут выстраиваться во всю ширину, а по мере сужения будут "тонуть" на следующую строку.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
div { border: 1px black solid;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

У них строка разбита на 12 колонок, номер в имени класса обозначает, сколько колонок занимает ячейка. Суффикс 'xs', 'sm', 'md' и 'lg' указывают, к какому виду экранов эта ширина относится. Например, `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">` означает, что на очень узком экране эта ячейка занимает 6 колонок, то есть 50% от ширины строки, а на умеренно широком дисплее - 4 колонки, или 33% ширины строки. Кроме того, `xs` ячейки никогда не перескакивают на следующую строку при сжатии окна, а остальные классы перескакивают, как только перестают помещаться в свой минимальный размер. Свойства классов указаны в [таблице](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid)

Соответственно, вы могли бы использовать `bootsrap` у себя вот так:

```
<div class="mytable container-fluid">
  <div class="grid row">
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В этом случае каждая ячейка занимает 25% ширины строки и минимальный размер ячейки `4*62px = 248px`. Как только контейнер сжимается настолько, что 25% от его ширины меньше минимального размера ячейки, крайняя ячейка перескочит на следующую строку. По мере сжатия третья, а потом и вторая ячейка отправятся на следующую строку, до тех пор, пока они все не выстроятся вертикально.

Если же вам хочется, чтобы сохранялась симметрия, то группы по две ячейки нужно объединить:

```
<div class="mytable container-fluid">
  <div class="grid row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="grid-item col-md-3"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

в этом случае по мере сжатия первым перескочит на следующую строку элемент `.col-md-6` и утащит с собой вложенные в него ячейки.

Вот, как-то так.

Но мне лично больше нравится второй вариант со специализированной вёрсткой под каждый размер. Как-то с ним я себя чувствовал более уверенно, чем с bootstrap. Тот мне всегда казался какой-то чёрной магией.